# Unable to create executable Jar in Dataflow SDK 2.1.0

Tags: java, maven, jar, google-cloud-dataflow

I created Jar with the following pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXXXXXXXXX</artifactId>
<version>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>prepare-agent</id>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                     </goals>
                 </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>summary</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <!--<version>3.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/java/basic.xml</ruleset>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/java/design.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hamcrest and JUnit are required dependencies of DataflowAssert, which 
        is used in the main code of DebuggingWordCount example. -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

maven command

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn package
```

Jar Command to execute

```
 java -jar XXXXXX-jar-with-dependencies.jar
      --runner=DataflowRunner
      --jobName=XXXXXXXXXX 
      --project=XXXXXXXXXX 
      --network=XXXXXXXXXX
      --subnetwork=XXXXXXXXXXXX 
      --workerMachineType=XXXXXXX 
      --region=XXXXXXXXXX 
      --maxNumWorkers=XXX 
      --stagingLocation=XXXXXXXXXX 
      --tempLocation=XXXXXXXXXXXX
      --dataflowJobFile=XXXXXXXXXX
```

The following error occurred

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown 'runner' specified 'DataflowRunner', supported pipeline runners [DirectRunner]
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1615)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:291)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataflowRunner
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
```

As a workaround for the above error, we added the following to the pom file and use DirectRunner only when testing.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When executing with the above workaround, the following error occurred.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to infer a coder and no Coder was specified. Please set a coder by invoking Create.withCoder() explicitly.
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create$Values.expand(Create.java:318) 
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create$Values.expand(Create.java:268)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:514)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:473)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:180)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.expand(BatchLoads.java:344)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.expand(BatchLoads.java:67)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:514) 
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:454)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:284)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expandTyped(BigQueryIO.java:1019)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:972)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:659)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:514)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:473)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:297)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Unable to provide a Coder for com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow.
Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
```

As a workaround for the above error, setCoder is set, but the result does not change.

In SDK 1.9.0 we were able to create executable Jar with maven.

If Jar can be created, can you give me a hint of how to change pom file and how to run jar?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java dependency?

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/